# mysql; how to analyse a slow query that occurs in only one database

Tags: mysql

I'm investigating some long running queries in my PRODUCTION mysql 5.7 database. 1 particular query is taking over 60 seconds.

My usual approach is to take a dump of the data from PROD, import it into a DEV database, reproduce the issue, then analyse and try out some tweaks to the query.

However, the exact same query in DEV is taking less than a second.

Obviously, the mysql configuration, table structure, record numbers, etc are all the same as in PROD.

The query itself is a select with joins across 3 tables with a where clause on each table; 2 of the tables have approx 15m records in them. My initial suspicion was the lack of indexes on the queried  columns, but the fact that in DEV it runs very fast would appear to disprove that.

What can I do to shed some light on this?

---

EXPLAIN results of my query:

PROD

```
EXPLAIN select this_.id as y0_ from event this_ inner join member m1_ on this_.member_id=m1_.id inner join event_type et2_ on this_.type_id=et2_.id where m1_.submission_id=40646 and this_.status in ('SUPPRESSED') and et2_.name in ('Salary') order by m1_.ni_number asc, m1_.ident1 asc, m1_.ident2 asc, m1_.ident3 asc, m1_.id asc, et2_.name asc limit 15;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------+-------------------+---------+--------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys                       | key               | key_len | ref                      | rows | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------+-------------------+---------+--------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | et2_  | NULL       | ALL    | PRIMARY                             | NULL              | NULL    | NULL                     |   17 |    10.00 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | this_ | NULL       | ref    | FK5C6729A2434DA80,FK5C6729AE4E22C6E | FK5C6729AE4E22C6E | 8       | iconnect.et2_.id         | 4166 |    10.00 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | m1_   | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,IND_submission_id           | PRIMARY           | 8       | iconnect.this_.member_id |    1 |     5.00 | Using where                                  |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------+-------------------+---------+--------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

DEV

```
EXPLAIN select this_.id as y0_ from event this_ inner join member m1_ on this_.member_id=m1_.id inner join event_type et2_ on this_.type_id=et2_.id where m1_.submission_id=40646 and this_.status in ('SUPPRESSED') and et2_.name in ('Salary') order by m1_.ni_number asc, m1_.ident1 asc, m1_.ident2 asc, m1_.ident3 asc, m1_.id asc, et2_.name asc limit 15;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+-------------------------------------+-------------------+---------+-----------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys                       | key               | key_len | ref             | rows  | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+-------------------------------------+-------------------+---------+-----------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | et2_  | NULL       | ALL  | PRIMARY                             | NULL              | NULL    | NULL            |    17 |    10.00 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | m1_   | NULL       | ref  | PRIMARY,IND_submission_id           | IND_submission_id | 8       | const           | 26644 |   100.00 | NULL                                         |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | this_ | NULL       | ref  | FK5C6729A2434DA80,FK5C6729AE4E22C6E | FK5C6729A2434DA80 | 8       | iconnect.m1_.id |     2 |     1.86 | Using where                                  |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+-------------------------------------+-------------------+---------+-----------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set, 1 warning (0.03 sec)
```

---

Have also spotted that the Cardinality of some of indexes accessed by this query are massively different between DEV and PROD:

FK5C6729AE4E22C6E: DEV=9, PROD=3792

IND_submission_id: DEV=2490, PROD=74220

Could this be impacting performance in PROD?

Comment: show the related  explain plan and the schema  for the tables involved (for PROD database)  ..

Comment: run `explain select ...`

Comment: Which engine do you use? MyISAM or InnoDB? If cardinality change try to make `analyze table event; analyze table member; analyze table event_type;` and run query again. If that is InnoDB then you can try to optimize tables.

Comment: Is the explain result on DEV different? if so - please post both. Also post create statements for all three tables (`SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>`). We need to see the indices.

Comment: Karol - it is InnoDB. In PROD, the application will do numerous updates/deletes on  these tables every day, whereas with DEV, the data is static. So I'm wondering if optimizing them will do the trick. Is there anything to suggest they need optimizing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query inefficiencies down to the tables containing more data than the index pages can hold. Increasing

> innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages

from 20 to 100, then running ANALYZE TABLE changed the execution plan for the query to be as expected, then running the query took less than 1 second.